# Custom (separate) metadata form in alfresco share

Tags: forms, customization, alfresco, alfresco-share

**Seemingly simple requirement**

I need a form containing 4 fields (textfield, authority, and date x2), that behaves exactly as does the edit metadata form, the fields representing 4 properties on the node.

This form however, should be available as a separate UI from the edit-metadata form, preferably in the way a UI-action is; a button with icon in the DocLibActions, and a popup form when that is clicked.

**Encountered problems**

My problem with using the UI action mechanism, is that I cannot link the fields to the properties. Therefore, each time the form opens, the current values available on the node are not loaded. Also, appropriate constraints are not automatically enforced. I cannot think of another way to implement this requirement either.

**The UI action way**

Starting it out as a UI action, I tried accessing the node in a custom field control ftl using the `form.destination` model variable holding the noderef. However, when I wanted to get the node properties with that, it turned out the `companyhome` object required for that in ftl is unavailable to a form control.

I then proceeded to write a custom java webscript that returns the 4 properties I need using a given nodeRef, and called it from my custom field control using javascript. This presents the following two issues:

- I have to pass the retrieved values to the form fields myself, presenting quite a challenge for the `date.ftl` controls, but much more even the `authority.ftl` control.
- Calling a webscript from the client side javascript adds another round-trip.

**Current form definition**

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="my-action">
      <forms>
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
               <show id="textProperty" />
               <show id="authorityProperty" />
               <show id="dateProperty1" />
               <show id="dateProperty2" />
            </field-visibility>

            <appearance>
                <set id="generalSet" appearance="bordered-panel" label="General" />
                <field id="textProperty" label="textProp" set="generalSet">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/propertyBasedTextfield.ftl">
                        <control-param name="propertyProvider">/alfresco/service/mark/custom/nodeProperties</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>

               <field id="authorityProp" label="Authority" set="generalSet" >
                   <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl" >
                    <control-param name="compactMode">true</control-param>
                   </control>
                </field>
                <field id="dateProperty1" label="Date 1" set="generalSet">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl" />
                </field>
                <field id="dateProperty2" label="Date 2" set="generalSet">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl" />
                </field>
            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>
```

How can I best go about implementing this requirement? Note that using a UI action is not mandatory; I can realize this any way I want.

Comment: You'd like to add a 2nd edit-form into the doclib? if yes, did you take a look how alfresco has implemented the default action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `Alfresco.doclib.Actions.onActionDetails()` function in the actions.js client-side module ([source code](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-head/symbols/src/components_documentlibrary_actions.js.html)). The easiest method is to register your own [custom action handler](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/doclib-client-side-template-and-action-extensions.html), which can be based on the code in `onActionDetails()`, but using your own custom form ID which exposes the basic form, e.g.

```
var templateUrl = YAHOO.lang.substitute(Alfresco.constants.URL_SERVICECONTEXT + "components/form?itemKind={itemKind}&itemId={itemId}&destination={destination}&mode={mode}&submitType={submitType}&formId={formId}&showCancelButton=true",
{
   itemKind: "node",
   itemId: nodeRef,
   mode: "edit",
   submitType: "json",
   formId: "***custom-form-id***"
});
var editDetails = new Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog(this.id + "-editDetails-" + Alfresco.util.generateDomId());
editDetails.setOptions({
   width: "40em",
   templateUrl: templateUrl,
   ...
});
```

You'll obviously need to add your custom form definition to a `share-config-custom.xml` file or similar, where you can also include your document library action definition.

You should not need to write any custom UI components.

Also you should not need to manually inject property values into the form when it is rendered by the UI, or write any web scripts to deal with the form submission - the forms framework will handle all of this for you if you use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great lead. However, what do you mean by 'full page'?

Comment: I may have mis-read your question. When you said you wanted your custom pop-up form to behave like the existing Edit Metadata action, I assumed you wanted a button within the pop-up that linked to a full page with a more detailed form. If that is not a requirement, then that would simplify things!

Comment: Suspected something along the line :P. It certainly does, thanks. However, I already use a custom action, so I'd think I can just use your custom handler with it. The only question that comes to mind then is, in the form definition's condition, do I put the action, or the content type containing the properties? I'll add my current definition to clarify.

Comment: It's not valid to embed the form config within the action, it must be within a `<config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">` (or similar) section. Also you will need an `id` attribute on your `<form>` element so that you can reference it from your action handler.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the bit about the second form definition